# Get selected month from Winforms month calendar?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a MonthCalendar control on my form. I have set it so that it selects an entire week at a time (from Sun to Sat).

At the top of the control, the user is able to select a month. How can I obtain the month that the user has selected? Issues rise when there is a week that contains days from two different months.

E.g. If user selects the week of Nov 29 2015 to Dec 5 2015 and has the month of November selected in the control. They could have December selected as well, I don't know how to tell.

Code for selecting week (it doesn't select from Sunday to Saturday but that's a problem for later):

```
int i = (int)MonthView1.SelectionStart.DayOfWeek;
Date d = MonthView1.SelectionStart;
MonthView1.SelectionStart = d.AddDays(1 - i);
MonthView1.SelectionEnd = d.AddDays(7 - i);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will use the month of the start of the selection. Is this what you want?

```
    private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime d = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start;
        Console.WriteLine(d.Month.ToString());
    }
```

You can easily change it to `monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.End` if using start is not what you want.

EDIT:

Putting your selection code in MouseDown event, I noticed the small selection (dotted line) box will always be on Monday, which is also start of selection. That means if Monday lies on the previous month, monthCalender will scroll to the previous month. Hence using `monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start` should fulfill your requirements.

EDIT2:

Maybe you tried to put everything in 1 callback? Here's my complete code. It won't glitch.

(Though the `monthCalendar1_DateChanged` might be called multiple times when you do a mouse down. The LAST time it is called will give you the correct Month)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.monthCalendar1.DateChanged += new System.Windows.Forms.DateRangeEventHandler(this.monthCalendar1_DateChanged);
        this.monthCalendar1.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.monthCalendar1_MouseDown);
    }

    private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime d = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start;
        Console.WriteLine(d.Month.ToString()); //Get the month selected. 
    }

    private void monthCalendar1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int i = (int)monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.DayOfWeek;
        DateTime d = monthCalendar1.SelectionStart;
        monthCalendar1.SelectionStart = d.AddDays(1 - i);
        monthCalendar1.SelectionEnd = d.AddDays(7 - i);
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue with this is that if December is the selected month, the first week of December from Sun to Sat has days in November. Using Start would say that the selected month is November. The same goes for End.

Comment: I get what you mean. I played around with the MonthCalendar and noticed a pattern. If I select by dragging from left to right, the calendar will scroll to next month if I select the last week of the month... If you provide some code of how you do selection, maybe we can work from there.

Comment: Edited my post to include that code - selection is done by the user clicking any day and it'll select that week from Sun to Sat. Selection must always be by week.

Comment: you're right, but unfortunately that automatic month switching calls itself over and over with each selection change, so even if a full week is selected with days from another month, it'll glitch out and stay on the current month. I tried adding my code to DateChanged, DateSelected, and MouseDown. It's always the same glitch.

Comment: I have added complete code to my answer. Give it a try :)